# Append element in xml file in opencv using cpp

Tags: c++, xml, opencv, file-storage

I am trying to append a new element in my opencv xml file which already has one element as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<acc type_id="opencv-ml-ann-mlp">
...
</_></weights></acc>
</opencv_storage>
```

I am trying to append one more element called micr as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<acc type_id="opencv-ml-ann-mlp">
...
</_></weights></acc>
  <micr type_id="opencv-ml-ann-mlp">
...
</_></weights></micr>
</opencv_storage>
```

But what I am getting is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<acc type_id="opencv-ml-ann-mlp">
...
  <micr type_id="opencv-ml-ann-mlp">
...
</_></weights></micr></_></weights></acc>
</opencv_storage>
```

I am using cv::FileStorage from opencv.

I want to know what is wrong with ::APPEND and if there is any alternative to achieve this.

Here's the code:

```
cv::FileStorage f("OCR.xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
...
ann.write(*f, "acc");    //In another function
...
f.release();

cv::FileStorage f("OCR.xml", cv::FileStorage::APPEND);
...
ann.write(*f, "micr");    //In another function
...
f.release();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us the code you're using, i.e. a [mcve], or it's impossible to know where you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Hi Miki, I have added the code, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this snippet. It seems to work as expected.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat layers = (Mat1i(2,1) << 5, 15);
    CvANN_MLP ann(layers);

    {
        FileStorage f("OCR.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
        ann.write(*f, "acc");
    }
    {
        FileStorage f("OCR.xml", FileStorage::APPEND);
        ann.write(*f, "micr");
    }

    FileStorage f("OCR.xml", FileStorage::READ);

    CvANN_MLP ann_acc;
    ann_acc.read(*f, cvGetFileNodeByName(*f, NULL, "acc"));

    CvANN_MLP ann_micr;
    ann_acc.read(*f, cvGetFileNodeByName(*f, NULL, "micr"));

    return 0;

    return 0;
}
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34547718/5008845) that you shouldn't mix save/load with write/read.

Comment: </_></weights></acc>
 <!-- resumed -->

<micr type_id="opencv-ml-ann-mlp">
This doesn't help when I try to do this

 annAcc.load("OCR.xml", "acc");
 annMICR.load("OCR.xml", "micr");

It gives me bad argument error, that you might be aware of.

Comment: That bad argument error was because of other mistake. It's working for .load(".xml", "") also. What if I keep using .load instead of .read as you suggested? How will it affect?